# Laravel 5.6 how to delete if there are any records of User

Tags: laravel, eloquent

> I'm trying to use updateOrCreate in that case but didn't work. So that's why i'm using this. I'll check database before store data. If there are any records of this user I'll delete that record. If there aren't any records I'll create records. Problem is how to delete if there are any records of User.

```
public function store(Request $request,Choice $choice){
    $time = $request->input('time');
    $user = Choice::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    if ($user === null) {
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
                ]);
            }
        return redirect()->route('choices.index');
    }
    else{
        $choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->orderBy('id')->get()->toArray();
        dd($choices);
        foreach ($choices as $index) {
            $index->delete();
        }
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
                ]);
            }
        return redirect()->route('choices.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using dd in else case ? that will just halt the process and another thing you are using delete in array, you need to use that in eloquent object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will be look like this,

```
public function store(Request $request,Choice $choice){
    $time = $request->input('time');
    $choice = Choice::where('user_id','=',Auth::id())->first();
    if ($choice === null) {
        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
                ]);
            }
    }
    else{
        $choices = Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->delete();

        foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
            Choice::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                'time'  => $time,
                'topic_id' => $key,
                'question_number' => $value,
                ]);
            }
    }
   return redirect()->route('choices.index');
}
```

If any confusion feel free to ask and I hope you understand.

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you sir. But how did you delete all records of user_id. And it will only delete records of user_id right?

Comment: just look at the line after else statement, that will delete all the choices of the current user

Comment: @SagarGautam redundant code. No need to perform a check for records to delete them.

Comment: @Waleed If we need to delete all records and then creating new, then your answer is ideal one but later it may be required to delete some choices, preserving some and adding new choices then we need to check record exist or not ;)

Comment: @SagarGautam Then we would use WhereNot or NotExist clause to prevent deleting of those file but writing redundant code is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call delete by user id which will make sure if there are any previous record it will be deleted.

```
public function store(Request $request,Choice $choice){

$time = $request->input('time');

// delete records which belong to user
Choice::where('user_id', Auth::id())->delete();

// add new records
foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
    Choice::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'time'  => $time,
        'topic_id' => $key,
        'question_number' => $value,
    ]);
}

return redirect()->route('choices.index');

}
```